# Remove function for vector c++

Tags: c++

I have a question regarding the remove() function for vector.

As I am trying to implement it in my own vector class. I was wondering how does the remove function works.

How does the function actually removes the element from the vector? And upon removal does the vector closes the gap created?

EDIT
I believe i have gotten the code to work thanks for the help!

```
template<class T>
bool MyVector<T>::RemoveAt(int i)
{
    if(i>=0 && i<count)
    {
        for(int x=i;x<count;x++)
        {
            arr[x] = arr[x+1];
        }
        pop_back();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The next element is being placed on place of the removed, the next after next is placed on place of the next, and so on for all elements after the removed one. `size` variable is then decremented by 1, and `capacity` stays the same

Comment: std::vector doesn't have a remove() method.  Do you mean erase()?  Also, there many be multiple correct solutions/optimizations (you will have to refer to the standard).  g++ includes their implementation in the header file.  If you mean your own thing that has nothing to do with std::vector then you decide.  Do you support iterators?  Do they need to stay valid if they point to something that is not yet removed  or are they invalidated?  Do you want to keep slack or do you want to free memory as soon as possible etc.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov so do i use a loop to assign the index + 1 to index until the end of vector and remove the last index, hence size--?

Comment: You may see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom

Comment: Your updated code has an out-of-bounds access during the final iteration of the loop.

Comment: @j6t oh you are right so do I just change the for loop to (int x=i;x<(count-1);x++). So to prevent the last index from going out of bound?

Comment: @Vincent You can do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about [vector::erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/), than it just moves elements that are to the right of the space to the left by n elements, where n is the size of the space being deleted, and of course it changes size by n.

If you are talking about [std::remove](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) than there is possible implementation, and I here will describe one of them: the algorithm moves each element that satisfies the condition to the corresponding position, erasing the element that was in this position

Comment: hi thanks for answering i was talking about erase and i finally understood after @AlexeyLarionov 's explanation.